# FB Groups And Website Integration

Tags: web, integration, facebook-group

I want to integrate a website with a Facebook Group.

1. What is the best approach to adding a link in the group to access the website?
2. Can Tabs be added to FB Groups?
3. Where can I find additional information on this specific topic?

Comment: can you provide additional info? do you have a host and a domain already?

Comment: yes, have domain, hosting service, ssl, FB developer status..

Answer (score 0):

**What is the best approach to adding a link in the group to access the website?**

The best approach to add a link is simply backlink to your website in every post you make. FB with automatically add your website title, meta description and a photo from your homepage to your post.

**Can Tabs be added to FB Groups?**

No Tabs cannot be added to FB group, if you want to add your website on FB, then use FB pages, not FB groups. FB pages are dedicated to businesses.

**Where can I find additional information on this specific topic?**

You can find more info about integrating your website with FB [HERE](https://www.facebook.com/help/190339107762990/)